# PySpark DateDiff function returns null

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm learning PySpark and trying to get the difference between two dates. I've tried multiple formats to get the difference but my code always returns null. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried converting the format to unix_timestamp,

```
newdf = df.select('date_str', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('date_to', 'yyyy-MM-dd')).alias('to'))
```

The next step was to cast the columns to timestamp or DateType()
I've tried to create a function

```
timeDiff = (F.unix_timestamp('date_to', format=timeFmt)
            - F.unix_timestamp('date_from', format=timeFmt))
df = df.withColumn("Duration", timeDiff)
```

Following is the code I'm trying to execute

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("2017–05–13"
 ,"2017–05–16"), ("2017–05–13","2017–07–23"), 
 ("2017–05–13","2018–05–13")], ['date_from', 'date_to'])

timeFmt = "yyyy-MM-dd"
timeDiff = (F.unix_timestamp('date_to', format=timeFmt)
            - F.unix_timestamp('date_from', format=timeFmt))
df = df.withColumn("Duration", timeDiff)

df.show()
dfs_5 = df.withColumn('date_diff', F.datediff(F.to_date(df.date_to), F.to_date(df.date_from)))
dfs_5.show()

newdf = df.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('date_from', 'yyyy-MM-dd')).alias('from'),from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('date_to', 'yyyy-MM-dd')).alias('to'))

newdf.show()
newdf.withColumn("diff_days", F.datediff("from", "to")).show()
```

I expect the difference between the columns date_to and date_from, but my code returns null.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Your example code works for me - no `nulls`. The *only* change I had to make is to add a `F.` in front of `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp` in the `newdf = ...` line.

Comment: I tinkered around with the code and followed the document. I was able to get the date diff after following the format:
```df = df.withColumn("date_from_format", F.date_format(F.to_date(F.col("date_from"), "yyyy-MM-dd"), "yyyy/MM/dd"))

df = df.withColumn("date_to_format", F.date_format(F.to_date(F.col("date_to"), "yyyy-MM-dd"), "yyyy/MM/dd"))```